# Returning error if the validation fails in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-validation

I am using ajax to populate the data to a database. The thing which I want is, I want to receive errors if the entered data fails validation. I have following code in my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $rules = $this->category->getRules();

    if ($request->validate($rules)->fails())
    {
        return Response::json(array(
            'success' => false,
            'errors' => $request->validate($rules)->getMessageBag()->toArray()

        ), 400);
    }

    $data = $request->all();
    $data['title'] = $request->title;
    $data['is_parent'] = $request->is_parent;
    $data['parent_id'] = $request->parent_id;
    $data['priority'] = $request->priority;
    $data['icon'] = $request->icon;
    $data['slug'] = $request->slug;
    $data['show_in_nav'] = $request->show_in_nav;
    $this->category->fill($data);
    $status = $this->category->save();
    if($status){
        return response()->json(['status'=>true,'data'=>'Category created successfully.']);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['status'=>false,'data'=>null]);
    }
}
```

It is still giving the error in console with 422 (Unprocessable Entity)but not in a json. How can I manage to get the errors in json so that I can show it to the user?

Comment: `$request->validate(...)` throws an exception on failure and returns the validated data not a validator instance, if validation fails the code never gets passed `$request->validate(...)` ... if you send a request that accepts json you will get json

Comment: @lagbox thanks for the immediate response but how can I achieve my desired result while handling data with ajax?

Comment: it returns json for you in the exception handler https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic the code you have is not even being ran, once the exception is thrown the exception handler takes over

Comment: If you make request class to validate the data send through the ajax request then it's easy to respond with json data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your efforts but I simply got my desired output by doing this in ajax:

```
error: function(response){   
    let data = response.responseJSON.errors;
    $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
    $( "<span class='text-danger'>"+value+"</span>" ).insertAfter( "#"+key );
});
}
```

Also I did not have to write condition in validation simply doing the following worked for me.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $rules = $this->category->getRules();
    $request->validate($rules);
    $data = $request->all();
    $data['name'] = $request->name;
    $data['is_parent'] = $request->is_parent;
    $data['parent_id'] = $request->parent_id;
    $data['priority'] = $request->priority;
    $data['icon'] = $request->icon;
    $data['slug'] = $request->slug;
    $data['show_in_nav'] = $request->show_in_nav;
    $this->category->fill($data);
    $status = $this->category->save();
    if($status){
        return response()->json(['status'=>true,'data'=>'Category created successfully.']);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['status'=>false,'data'=>null]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can make form request class to add validation logic and respond validation errors as json data. At first, create form request class using artisan command.

```
php artisan make:request CategoryRequest
```

This will create `CategoryRequest.php` inside `App\Http\Requests` directory like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CategoryRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
             // add validation rules here
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error messages that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            // add validation error messages associated with rules or you can leave this empty
        ];
    }
}
```

Now, Add your validation rules and messages in the above functions. In order to return validation errors in json format, just add following function to above class:

```
/**
 * Return validation errors as json response
 *
 * @param Validator $validator
 */
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    $response = [
        'status' => 'failure',
        'status_code' => 400,
        'message' => 'Bad Request',
        'errors' => $validator->errors(),
    ];

    throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($response, 400));
}
```

And don't forget add following at the top of CategoryRequest class:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
```

Now, you can get errors in json format. You can access errors in the response like `response.errors`

I hope you understand.

Comment: the validation exception will cause the exception handler to return json for you already if the request is asking for json ... first paragraph https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic